# Стык и расчленение союзов

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: **Это значит, что (1) для того (2) чтобы узнать, надо прийти.** 
Пояснив, расставьте, пожалуйста, знаки препинания.
P.S. Автор не хотел подчеркнуть логическое ударение на первой части союза "для того чтобы".

Comment: Тут такая ситуация, по-моему: во-первых, "для того чтобы" - это составной союз, расчленять который нет причин (http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach3/); во-вторых, в этом предложении стык союзов "что" и "для того чтобы", следовательно, смотрим после придаточной части, где мы не находим "то", "но" или "так". Благополучно ставим запятую после "что".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну все верно. ****Это значит, что, для того  чтобы узнать, надо прийти****